# Simplest way to Convert an existing Method to generic object Type

Tags: c#, reflection

Let's assume I have an existing method which ALWAYS returns a variable of type OldClassType

```
//Takes 1 parameter p1
//Returns a variable of type OldClassType, after doing a bunch of logic.
protected OldClassType MyMethod(int32 p1)
{
   OldClassType myVar = new OldClassType();
   myVar.name = "Hello";
   myVar.age = "36";

   return myVar;
}
```

Now, I have a NewClassType which has exactly the same  properties as OldClassType but is of a different namespace. I need to convert the same method (MyMethod) so that instead of ALWAYS returning OldClassType, it should return a variable of type either OldClassType or  NewClassType - based on a newly added parameter useNewType

So something like :

```
//Takes 2 parameter: p1 and useNewType - which determines when to use the NewClassType or default to the OldClassType
//Returns a variable of type object, after doing a bunch of logic. I'll modify the Call to this new modified method to cast the object to the appropriate Type (OldClassType/NewClassType)
protected object MyMethod(int32 p1, bool useNewType)
{  
   object myVar = new object();
   myVar.name = "Hello"; // Do I use PropertyInfo and then set value?
   myVar.age = "36";

   return myVar; 
}
```

EDIT:
One additional piece of information is that the OldClassType will be removed from the code in the future. So I'm trying to find the solution with least impact.

I was in fact wondering if the use of dynamic will solve it , ie minimize the changes to support NewClassType and when will the time to remove the OldClassType, I can simple change one line where I init it- example

```
protected dynamic MyMethod(int32 p1, bool useNewType)
{  
   dynamic myVar = (useNewType) ? new NewClassType() : new OldClassType(); // Is this allowed?

   //So all code below stays exactly the same
   myVar.name = "Hello"; 
   myVar.age = "36";

   return myVar; 
}
```

Comment: Can you still change anything about `OldClassType`, like implementing an interface with the common properties between old and new type?

Comment: Return a common interface?

Comment: No I cannot change anything about OldClassType and one additional info is that the OldClassType will eventually be removed from the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could make `NewClassType` derive from `OldClassType` so that it inherits all of its base type members.

```
public class NewClassType : OldClassType { }
```

You'd then have to make your method Generic, like this:

```
protected T MyMethod<T>(int p1) where T : OldClassType, new()
{
    T myVar = new T();
    myVar.name = "Hello";
    myVar.age = "36";

    return myVar;
}
```

I don't think you should use a bool value to specify if you want to return an instance of your new class type, you can just do:

```
var o = MyMethod<NewClassType>(10);
```

You could even define an overloaded method that still returns `OldClassType` but uses your generic method under the covers:

```
protected OldClassType MyMethod(int p1)
{
    return MyMethod<OldClassType>(p1);
}
```

Comment: What if OldClassType is going to be deprecated in the near future... so I cannot inherit from it and all sources of this OldClassType will be removed?

Comment: @Gotcha Then you have to either introduce an interface or do some sort of mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid reflection, it is tricky and potentially slow.

Add a constructor to `NewClassType` that copies an `OldClassType`:

```
class NewClassType {
    public NewClassType( OldClassType old )
    {
        Name = old.Name;
        Age = old.Age;
        . . . 
    }
    . . . 
}
```

and then:

```
protected object MyMethod(int32 p1, bool useNewType)
{  
    OldClassType myVar = new OldClassType();
    myVar.name = "Hello";
    myVar.age = "36";

    if (!useNewType) return myVar; 
    return new NewClassType( myVar );
}
```